# CIVICRM WP critical error after migrating to PHP 8.1

Tags: wordpress, php

I am running CIVICRM  on WordPress 6.4.1 with PHP 7.4.  Upgraded both platforms to the latest versions.  After changing php version from 7.4 to 8.1, I get a WP critical error.  After enabling WP debug, I get the following message.

Any idea on how to correct this?

Deprecated: auto_detect_line_endings is deprecated in ..../wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php on line 596

Fatal error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in ..../wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/com.pogstone.fancytokens/fancytokens.civix.php on line 149
There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

Comment: Beautiful.  It worked.  Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

There hasn't been a release for fancytokens in a while but as a workaround you can just edit that fancytokens.civix.php file and change the `{0}` to `[0]` on line 149.

For the other one just remove line 596 from your civicrm.settings.php. There was a pre-upgrade notice in 5.62 about it.